# Перезагружается компьютер после press any key

Tags: windows, bios

Добрый вечер!

Хочу поставить на ноутбук windows 10 с флэшки, ставил с этой же флешки на другие компьютеры ( 100% рабочая ).

перезагружаю компьютер, жму f11 , выбираю флэшку, на экране:
press any key to boot, жму, компьютер просто перезагружается и все. Перепробовал разные настройки в биосе, без изменений, может кто сталкивался? Спасибо!

P.S

Будет здорово если подскажете какие нибудь форумы, где смогут ответить на этот вопрос!

Comment: ноутбук не слишком ли староват?

Comment: Да нет, года 2 ему

Comment: Чтобы проверить правильность ваших действий и настроек биоса, создайте другую загрузочную флешку, необязательно с win10, и посмотрите получится ли загрузиться с нее. Больше в голову, ничего не приходит, извините.

Comment: Было нечто похожее, связано было с тем что пытался использовать usb 3.0 но на матери не было драйвера для 3.0, возможно причина в этом